# Wifi Repeater – Set Interface down by Default (dhcpcd)

Tags: raspbian, wifi, access-point, pi-1, hostapd

I use a RPI 1 as wifi repeater with two wireless dongles. I configured it using `hostapd` and `dnsmasq`.

I want the pi only to be connected to the internet if there is somebody connected to my access point. So I wrote this service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start hostapd_cli
After=hostapd.service
BindsTo=hostapd.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd_cli -p /var/run/hostapd -a /home/pi/autoConnect.sh -i wlan0 
TimeoutSec=0
RemainAfterExit=yes
GuessMainPID=no

[Install]
WantedBy=hostapd.service
```

Where `autoConnect.sh` is:

```
if [[ "$2" == "AP-STA-CONNECTED" ]]; then
    if ! ip link show wlan1 | grep -q "UP"; then
        sudo ip link set wlan1 up
    fi

elif [[ "$2" == "AP-STA-DISCONNECTED" ]]; then
    sleep 120 &&
    if ! sudo hostapd_cli all_sta | grep -q "AUTHORIZED"; then
        sudo ip link set wlan1 down
    fi
fi
```

It work's, but after a reboot the pi connects to the internet, which I want to avoid. 
Adding

```
wlan0
noup
```

to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` didn't do the trick. (Starting `wpa_supplicant` through my script is not possible, because it fails when I have to restart `hostapd`.)

So I would like to know **how to set an interface down by default?**

(Maybe you got even hints for a better solution in general.)

**EDIT:**

I followed Ingo's suggestions and changed completely to `systemd` and disabled the `wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service`.
I now use this service and script to automatically connect and disconnect to the internet:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/wpa-cli@wlan0.service
[Unit]
Description=wpa_cli to auto connect wifi on event
After=network-online.target wpa_supplicant@%i.service sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
BindsTo=wpa_supplicant@%i.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_cli -i %I -a /home/pi/autoConnectWLAN.sh -B
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$2" in
    AP-STA-CONNECTED)
        systemctl start wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service 
        ;;

    AP-STA-DISCONNECTED)
        sleep 60
        if ! wpa_cli -i wlan0 all_sta | grep -q "AUTHORIZED"; then
            systemctl stop wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service

        fi
        ;;
```

I now wonder if it would be possible to achieve what I want by just defining dependencies between the two `wpa_supplicant@.service`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also asked: "*Maybe you got even hints for a better solution in general.*" I prefer to use `systemd-networkd` because it has all in one. Using two USB/wifi dongle simplifies it a lot. So my hint is to look at [Access point as WiFi repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866). It does not fit exactly your needs but it should not be a big problem to adapt it to your problem.

Both interfaces **wlan0** and **wlan1** are handled independent from the other with interface specific versions of `wpa_supplicant` services (e.g. wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service). You can setup each interface for what you need and set dependencies between the two services.

And to answer your question: with this setup it is easy to disable e.g. **wlan0** on startup with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

(If you like to get some assistance please don't hesitate to ask).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd like to change completely to `systemd`. Unfortunately I got stuck [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/91773/92303), where you guessed it to be a problem with the old hardware.

Comment: I finally made it working. How would achieve what I want with `systemd`? Is there a possibility to do it without using `wpa_cli -a SCRIPT.sh`?

Comment: @jake I have just found that it could be that there was a wrong option set for wpa_supplicant used by `systemd-networkd`: [Replacing hostapd with wpa_supplicant](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95028/79866) but I do not have a feedback now if this fixed the problem, waiting for it.

Comment: Is it possible to get what I want without an additional service? Otherwise I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @jake What do you mean with "*additional service*"? Where to add a service?

Comment: I mean my `wpa-cli@wlan0.service`. It would be a cleaner solution if I could define a condition inside the `wpa_supplicant@wlan1service` to only be running if somebody is connected to the access point.

Comment: @jake I will look but have just no idea. The problem is to get information from a running service (the access point). You cannot use dependencies because they are only used to start/stop/delay etc. services depending on other services. With a running service **systemd** is satisfied. Running wpa_cli as daemon for this is a good idea. But if we can use [systemd-notify](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-notify.html) in any way I would prefer this.

Comment: @jake I have made **ifplugd** available again for Raspbian: [Make ifplugd available again since Raspbian Stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/96604/79866). But it doesn't make much difference to use `wpa_cli -a SCRIPT.sh`. So only a comment to this.